# Difference between usage of session_id and remember_user_token by a Rails application with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, devise

I am using Devise-1.5.4 with Rails 3.0.20. Here are the facts that I am aware of:

1. There is a Cookie for session_id with the browser, which helps a normal application uniquely track a session. There may or may not be a user signed in.
2. If a user is signed in (and assuming he selected remember_me), there is another Cookie for remember_user_token with the browser.
3. In my application, I use (devise provided) methods like [`current_user`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.5/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L55), [`authenticate_user!`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.5/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L46) to validate a user.
4. The above methods call [`authenticate!`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.5/lib/devise/strategies/rememberable.rb#L19), which itself calls [`serialize_from_cookie`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.5/lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb#L114), that uses `remember_token` to authenticate the user.

I am a bit confused about the usage of session_id.

1. When is that used, and how?
2. If a user is signed in, for my rails application (or devise) to uniquely identify the user, will it ever use session_id?
3. What happens when user doesn't selects remember_me (and there is no `remember_token`)? How does devise validate the current_user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The session cookie, as the name suggests, is valid for the current browser session only, i.e. it is not available if the browser is quit and reopened (unless you do something like restore session in which case browser restores the cookies from the previous session).

Remember cookie for extending the login period beyond the current session.

Devise uses warden and the way it works is :

1) Devise registers several strategies with warden - viz : Session key based auth, auth from params, auth from remember token etc.
2) When the request comes in warden runs each of those strategies
3) If any one strategy succeeds in authenticating the request warden sets the "user" (which you get via current_user helper method later) and stops running subsequent strategies
4) If none of the strategies succeed it is declared that no user is currently logged in (and current_user would return nil)

So in your case, if the session_id is set (i.e. the key `warden.user.user.key` is set to a valid user id) the session based authentication strategy succeeds and the user is considered logged in. If that session is not available then warden moves on to next strategy and subsequently arrives at the "auth from remember_token" strategy. This strategy checks for the existence of a remember cookie. If presents, gets the token from that cookie, verifies if it is still valid and not expired. If so then it sets the "user" and user is considered logged in.
If the token has expired again the user is considered as not logged in.

If while logging in user does not select remember_me then the remember token is not set in the remember cookie. In such a case if the user closes his browser and opens it again (without restoring the previous session) then user is no longer logged into your system.

Reading through Warden documentation and warden code would be very helpful to understand this whole flow. You can put in debug print/log lines in the warden code and run your app to understand how all of this is working.

Comment: Thanks for an elaborate answer. Very helpful. Will definitely go through `warden` code, to explore.