# Optimise query made by Devise to find user based on remember_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Devise-1.5.4 with Rails 3.0.20.

Devise provides methods like [`current_user`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.5/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L55), [`authenticate_user!`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.5/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L46) which call [`authenticate!`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.5/lib/devise/strategies/rememberable.rb#L19), which itself calls [`serialize_from_cookie`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.5/lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb#L114), that uses `remember_token` to authenticate the user.

Also, the `serialize_from_cookie` method receives `id` as a parameter, so that it queries `Users` table on the primary key (which is automatically an optimised query).

However, I see queries like `select * from users where remember_token = 'XXXXXX'` in MySQL logs.

Since the users table has grown huge, these queries are getting slower. I have following questions regarding this:

1. I am not able to debug where (in code) is Devise making such queries?
2. How can I optimise these queries (apart from adding indexes)?

Comment: How big's your user table? Also have you tried `bundle open devise` and throwing debuggers in the gem to play around with it?

Comment: Remembering a user should actually be a rare action. How slow are such queries?

Comment: Is this still a question for you (i.e. after this answer has been provided : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686247/difference-between-usage-of-session-id-and-remember-user-token-by-a-rails-applic/25687145#25687145 ) ?

Comment: @D-side - Why should that be a rare action? IMO, almost everyone uses remember me. Also, the queries take approx 6-8 sec.

Comment: @brahmana - Yes. As per http://stackoverflow.com/a/25687145/2036529, I understand that Devise uses multiple strategies to authenticate user. However, as mentioned in this question, there is also an `id` parameter to find a user based on `remember_token` via an optimised query.

Searching a user solely based on `remember_token` is something I couldn't find (in code too). Need help regarding that.

Comment: "apart from adding indexes" - why this constraint? That's THE SOLUTION which you should be looking at. Indexes are specifically devised for that purposes, to avoid a full table scan for such look ups. I don't understand your reservation around adding an index.

Comment: Because then Insert/Updates/Delete speed on `Users` will degrade, which of course I don't want to happen. I can't keep adding indexes in all columns which are being queried. I wish to know if there are any other options.

Comment: Utsav, I suggest you look a little more thoroughly in the code. You can just print the current stack in any of the functions you have mentioned in your question to find out the source of other functions. Look for individual ODM/ORM adapter related modules. Additionally I agree with @amit_saxena. Index is the way to speed up queries. No doubt your writes will get slower but that's the natural trade off. Users table is read more often than being written. So couple more indexes won't hurt the read performance that much. I don't think there is any other option but to modify devise itself.

Comment: @UtsavKesharwani have you measured by what amount your write performance degrades? I would say it will be insignificant compared to the exponential gain in read performance. Again, the sole purpose of indexes is to solve the problem you are trying to solve. On a large enough dataset, none of the programmatic approaches you are looking for will work. Rule of thumb for any kind of database - always avoid the dreaded full table scan - if you are doing that, you are definitely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise does a query to ensure a same token is not already set while setting a new `remember_token`.

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb#L146

```
# Generate a token checking if one does not already exist in the database.
def remember_token #:nodoc:
  loop do
    token = Devise.friendly_token
    break token unless to_adapter.find_first({ remember_token: token })
  end
end
```